# Old OS partition is seen in BIOS after completely formating the drive and installing new OS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

I used to have a dual boot with Mac OS X and Windows 10. Some time ago my GPU crashed and I bought a new one. As I was doing a system redo I thought I didn't need OSX partition anymore.

I reinstalled Windows 10 via  USB and completely deleted all partitions from the drive to have it clean. Then did a full install on the wiped drive.

But I'm having problems with BSOD crashed and freezes on my new system and I'm currently trying to find out what's wrong. Sometimes after a crash, I boot into BIOS and the only UEFI partition I can see in BIOS is "Mac OS X".

This is really weird because I thought I deleted that from the drive?

What's weird is after a reboot I can find my Windows 10 UEFI boot partition, but the Mac OSX one still remains.

What's going on here, and how can I remove that OSX partition from my drive?

[This is what the boot BIOS looks like with a windows 10 USB inserted as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjl4s.jpg)

UPDATE:

This is getting even weirder. I tried switching to a SSD that hasn't even been used in this computer and when booting I still see the "Mac OS X" UEFI boot option. What is going on?

Comment: Is this actual apple hardware?

Comment: @Yorik No it's not.

Comment: What you're seeing is the EFI boot manager list, which is stored in NVRAM. This is *not* a list of partitions, but of *boot loader programs.* Mostly these are files stored on disk, but sometimes they can be other things, like network boot options. The key, though, is that they're maintained as a list in NVRAM. That list may or may not be accurate. Also, on EFI-based systems (yours is EFI-based, not BIOS-based), boot loaders are stored on the EFI System Partition (ESP). Boot loaders can persist there even after you've deleted an OS's partition, so you might want to clean up the ESP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I fixed the issues.

I downloaded a program called "easyuefi" where I could see all the efi partitions and just delete the OSX one.

I still have problems with Windows 10 crashing and freezing, disk utilization reaches 100% and everything breaking. But I believe this is not connected to my issue with booting.